# Nuget package (Flee) is outputting .dll for incorrect framework

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, .net-standard-2.0, flee

In our solution, we have three relevant projects to this issue. Below is a diagram that displays them:

[image: dependency diagram]

Project **A** runs tests on **C**, which implements the [Flee](https://github.com/mparlak/Flee) nuget package. This package apparently supports both `.NET Framework` and `.NET Core`. When I examine the contents of the package directory in my local nuget cache, it has two different dlls: `Flee.Net45.dll` and `Flee.Standard20.dll`.

The problem is that when running the tests in **A**, the following error occurs for *all* tests relating to **C**:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
Could not load file or assembly Flee.NetStandard20, [...] The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The first thing I did was check the `bin` folder: that's when I see that the `Flee.Net45.dll` sitting there. Which seems to be correct, since the project **A** is using `.NET Framework`. In the `csproj` file for project **A**, the framework is set as: `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>`.

To troubleshoot further, I set up a temporary `xUnit Test Project (.NET Core)` (that's project **B**), and copied the relevant tests across. They all passed - and in the `bin` folder, it showed `Flee.NetStandard20.dll`, which is what I expected.

***Question***

When I run the tests in a project that targets `.NET Framework`, why is it looking for `Flee.Standard20.dll` at runtime? Does this look like an issue with the `Flee` package? Or would it be a configuration issue in project **A**?

Comment: Sounds like a .NET bug to me more than anything. What's the behaviour if your test project targets net45?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test that, as visual studio informs me that a `.NET Framework 4.5` project cannot reference a `.NET Standard 2.0` one.

Comment: was just going to say that won't work, it's only for net461 plus. I bet this is a bug around that